# Native undo role for the menu bar does not work after programmatic value changes

Tags: javascript, electron

### Code

I am building an [application menu](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu) for the menu bar, and I am using [roles](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu-item#roles) to automate some pre-defined functionalities like so:

```js
{
  label: 'File',
  submenu: []
},
{
  label: 'Edit',
  submenu: [
    { role: 'undo' },
    { role: 'redo' },
    { type: 'separator' },
    { role: 'cut' },
    { role: 'copy' },
    { role: 'paste' }
  ]
},
{
  label: 'View',
  submenu: []
},
...
```

### Issue

The following code part renders the menu and works like magic: `{ role: 'undo' }` but only for normal operations.

However, when you programmatically replace the value of a form control (textbox, texarea, etc), and then do some manual changes to that form control, the **Undo** feature will no longer work.

What could have I missed on this? Is this a bug or something? Below are the versions of software used.

### Environment

| Software | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Electron | `12.2.3` |
| Node.js | `14.16.0` |
| MacOS | `10.13.6` |

Comment: What are you trying to undo? Does Chromium undo the same action when using the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Simply typing on an HTML textbox (`<input type="textbox">`) and then I hit **undo** through the menu bar or through the shortcut key, it doesn't work either way.

Comment: @AbelCallejo that sounds like a bug. What platform? If you can reproduce it in an Electron Fiddle, then submit it on the Electron issue tracker to get it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

As Electron's [Roles](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu-item#roles) are only an extension of Chrome's functionality, the real test is to see if the same occurs when not using Electron.

I have tested your problem in both a standard html code base and an Electron code base.

## Standard HTML Code Base

In the below file I have two text fields. One is the input field and the other is to provide feedback, just to be sure.

The `button` is to dynamically append some `text` to the end of the input field.

To test:

1. Type some text into the input field.
2. Try **undo** and **redo** functionality. `// Success`

   - Windows: Ctrl-Z and Ctrl-Y respectively.
   - MacOS:   Cmd-Z and Shift-Cmd-Z respectively.
3. Now click the `button` to append some text.
4. Try **undo** and **redo** again. `// Failure`

After dynamically adding the text, undo and redo no longer works. Why? I don't know why, but this appears to be standard functionality for Chrome.

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Undo / Redo Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <label for="input">Input: </label>
            <input type="text" id="input">
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Append 'text'">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="output">Output: </label>
            <input type="text" id="output" disabled>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        let input = document.getElementById('input');
        let output = document.getElementById('output');

        input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
            output.value = input.value;
        });

        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            let value = input.value + ' text';
            input.value = value;
            output.value = value;
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

---

## Electron Code Base

Now, let's move the exact same html code over into an Electron application, so we can test it with the `Edit` -> `Undo` / `Redo` menu as well.

Testing via the keyboard shortcuts yields the same result as above.

Let's test it with the menu:

1. Type some text into the input field.
2. Select `edit` -> **`undo`** and **`redo`** functionality. `// Succees`
3. Now click the `button` to append some text.
4. Try `edit` -> **`undo`** and **`redo`** again. `// Failure`

The same result. After dynamically adding the text, undo and redo no longer works. A reflection of the Standard HTML Code Base.

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
'use strict';

const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

const nodePath = require("path");

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        fullscreen: false,
        resizable: true,
        movable: true,
        minimizable: true,
        maximizable: true,
        enableLargerThanScreen: true,
        closable: true,
        focusable: true,
        fullscreenable: true,
        frame: true,
        hasShadow: true,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        show: false,
        icon: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'icon.png'),
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
            enableRemoteModule: false,
            devTools: (! electronApp.isPackaged),
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
'use strict';

// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

`index.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Undo / Redo Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <label for="input">Input: </label>
            <input type="text" id="input">
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Append 'text'">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="output">Output: </label>
            <input type="text" id="output" disabled>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        let input = document.getElementById('input');
        let output = document.getElementById('output');

        input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
            output.value = input.value;
        });

        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            let value = input.value + ' text';
            input.value = value;
            output.value = value;
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Tested using:

- Electron: 17.1.0
- Node: 16.13.0
- Chrome: 98.04.4758.102

Tested on:

- Windows: 10
- MacOS: 10.15.7

---

## The Memento & Command Design Patterns

You could try and hook your `undo` and `redo` with something like `execCommand` but I think, if you're wanting to do it right, make it scalable and readable then you should really implement something along the lines of the [Memento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) and [Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) design patterns.

Though a fair bit of work to setup, once working, it could be applied to any `<form>` field on the page, not only `<input type="text">` and `<textarea>`.

But why stop there, make it applicable to page or application wide functionality as well (where it can be applied). EG: 'delete', 'rename', 'move', 'post', 'settings update', etc.